# iOS UICollectionView zoom on cell in center

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass is not correctly enlarging the cell that's in the center of the UICollectionView. Instead, my UICollectionViewCell disappears and reappears as I scroll horizontally. **My guess is that the issue is with the ACTIVE_DISTANCE value. What is ACTIVE_DISTANCE and how is it used in the following code?**

I'm following the WWDC 2012 Lecture Advanced UICollectionView tips and their code looks like this...

```
#define ITEM_SIZE 200
#define ACTIVE_DISTANCE 200
#define ZOOM_FACTOR 0.3

-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE);
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 50;
}
return self;
}



-(NSArray*) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
NSArray* array = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes in array) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect)) {
        CGFloat distance = CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect) - attributes.center.x;
        CGFloat normalizedDistance = distance / ACTIVE_DISTANCE;
        if (ABS(distance) < ACTIVE_DISTANCE) {
            CGFloat zoom = 1 + ZOOM_FACTOR*(1 - ABS(normalizedDistance));
            attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeScale(zoom, zoom, 1.0);
            attributes.zIndex = round(zoom);
        }
    }
}
return array;
}
```

In my code, my init method simply looks like

```
-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}
```

and my delegate method in my viewcontroller ooks like this

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return CGSizeMake(260, 390);
}
```

What should my ACTIVE_DISTANCE value be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
With a zoom of 0.3, my cells would begin to overlap each other. As soon as they overlapped, with a different cell, they would vanish. By reducing the zoom to about 0.05, it fixed the problem!